Seemingly strange results in Search Kit? (Or, how do I...?)
Search Kit is returning seemingly strange results. E.g. I am searching for Contacts who have a contribution. I expect Search Kit to return list of contacts, but it returns list of donations. That is, contacts are listed multiple times (one time for every donation).
If I choose to Group by Age bracket (as recommended here: How to count individuals by age bracket?), then I get spectacularly wrong results. Probably, total amounts of donors/total sums are counted multiple times (for every donation a contact has made).
In screenshot above I can Group contacts by Contact ID, then I get the correct number of results, but in that case I can't use grouping by Age bracket.
How do I get a list of Contacts (every contact once) when looking for Contacts that have made a Contribution in Search Kit?


You could do it in two steps:

One SK to create a smart group of contacts who have made donations
eg "Contributors"
One SK to create a listing grouped by age bracket,
with a filter condition of "In groups" "Contributors"


Can searchkit use smart groups?

@themak yes - there's a WHERE filter for Contacts (which is confusing because it seems like you should join Contacts to Groups, but that won't catch smart groups).

Aidan's solution is workable here, because you aren't, e.g., asking for the totals of donations by age group. But if you did, there's a more advanced technique.
You can use SearchKit results in a second SearchKit query. You can do that by creating a display of type "Entity".  So if, e.g., you needed total amounts by age group:

You'd make one search of contacts joined to contributions, with total amounts, grouped by contact, then save it as an entity.

Then you could make a second query where you take contacts and join to the results of query 1. Then you group by age group.


By pre-grouping in query 1, you take what would ordinarily be a "one-to-many" join (contacts to contributions) and turn it into a "one-to-one" join. That prevents any duplication of rows to throw off your numbers.
This is actually the most common application of the Entity display - you need to group by two criteria without duplicate rows throwing off your results.

SearchKit might seem strange at first if you are not familiar with the basics of SQL. You might be interested to read over an intro to SQL to understand how joins work. Basically, when you join one table to another, SQL will return a row for every matching join. You can find lots of illustrations out there to help you with the concept, like this one, which shows that a contact with multiple contributions will return multiple rows:



Is there a way the Search search results return only unique contact ids (i.e. contacts rather than contributions) in such search? 2) This SQLish behavior also means wrong sums of Contact IDs (not sum of unique, but of every duplicate) and money when counting all together.


that second blue line on the right is confusing me!

@petednz-fuzion - note the top section is two separate tables.

LOL. no i hadn't picked that up, just read left col and hten right col

Yup - me too when I first looked at.
